# Why is it so difficult to stop a render in progress?

Tags: rendering

This relates to both EEVEE and Cycles.

The issue is I carefully set up my project to render an animation, everything is perfect, but sometimes we forget something or there's an issue I need to diagnose so I hit the ESC key to stop the render. But it does not stop.

Repeated presses of the  <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, either with the render window maximized or changing focus back to the main Blender interface, do not kill the render, at least not until after the current frame is finished, or until several more frames have rendered.

Fast rendering scenes of just a few seconds are not egregious, but many of my renders are usually more than a minute/frame, sometimes several minutes /frame. A couple of times it's taken nearly half-an-hour to kill the render. This is not acceptable. I can kill a render in AE with a single press of  <kbd>Esc</kbd>, no matter the complexity of the project.

What is the issue with Blender? This behavior has persisted since I first started with 2.79 up through 3.0.1 and over several different computers and video cards.

If you have a suggestion on how to kill the render, aside from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Del</kbd> (that creates a whole other set of problems) I am all ears.

AMD 5950, 128GB RAM, RTX3090/24GB, lots of free M.2 SSD HDD.

Comment: Click the X to close the render window?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I believe this is the same as Esc. [link] (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/canceling-render-takes-too-much-time) I saw the answer to essentially the same question and the problem may relate to how renderers "chunk" the image and send it to the CPU/GPU. Since my most recent experiences have been on the GPU and very large sized tiles, this may be directly related. If so, this is an engineering/developer issue. I think there's a Nobel Prize in the offing for the saint who solves this problem.